# Special reshape in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider a 3x3 `char` dataframe:

```
example <- data.frame(one = c("a","b","c"),
             two = c("a","b","b"),
             three = c ("c","a","b"))
```

I want to resize these data to 6x2 and add the following content:

```
desired <- data.frame(one = c("a","a","b","b",
                              "c","b"),
                      two = c("a","c","b","a","b","b"))
```

For the original example dataframe, I want to `rbind()` the contents of example`[,2:3]` beneath each row index.

This can be achieved by:

```
ex <- as.matrix(example)

des <- as.data.frame(rbind(ex[,1:2], ex[,2:3]))
```

Maybe using `library(tidyverse)` for an arbitrary number of columns would be nicer?

Answer (score 3):

For each pair of columns, transpose the sub-data.frame defined by them and  coerce to vector. Then coerce to data.frame and set the result's names.
The code that follows should be scalable, it does not hard code the number of columns.

```
desired2 <- as.data.frame(
  lapply(seq(names(example))[-1], \(k) c(t(example[(k-1):k])))
)
names(desired2) <- names(example)[-ncol(example)]

identical(desired, desired2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

The code above rewritten as a function.

```
reformat <- function(x){
  y <- as.data.frame(
    lapply(seq(names(x))[-1], \(k) c(t(x[(k-1):k])))
  )
  names(y) <- names(x)[-ncol(x)]
  y
}

reformat(example)
example %>% reformat()
```

Another example, with 6 columns input.

```
ex1 <- example
ex2 <- example
names(ex2) <- c("fourth", "fifth", "sixth")
ex <- cbind(ex1, ex2)

reformat(ex)
ex %>% reformat()
```

Comment: This is a clean method, but I'm receiving an error when defining the function:   "unexpected ")" in ")". I'm wondering if this has something to do with `/(k)`?

Comment: @M1996rg Maybe it has. `\(k)` is a new lambda introduced in R4.1.0. Try `function(k)`. Time to update R?

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach using `tidyr::pivot_longer` may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(example, -one, values_to = "two") %>% 
  select(-name)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   one   two  
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     a    
#> 2 a     c    
#> 3 b     b    
#> 4 b     a    
#> 5 c     b    
#> 6 c     b
```

Answer (score 1):

A base-R solution with `Map`:

```
#iterate over example$one, example$two, and example$three at the same
#time, creating the output you need.
mylist <- Map(function(x ,y ,z ) {
 data.frame(one = c(x, y), two = c(y, z))
},
example$one #x,
example$two #y,
example$three #z)


do.call(rbind, mylist)
    one two
a.1   a   a
a.2   a   c
b.1   b   b
b.2   b   a
c.1   c   b
c.2   b   b
```